# How do I sync in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

According to Flutter documentation "Add Firebase to your Android app" I need to

"Finally, press "Sync now" in the bar that appears in the IDE: "

after adding Firebase to my project but "Sync now" does not appear anywhere in the IDE. I have followed the procedure in "Windows install Flutter" documentation 4 times but each time it fails to compile.

I tried Googling the error messages but no one else has reported a similar problem. I did see that at one time there was a sync option in the File menu list but it is not in Android Studio 3.5.1.

I can only suspect that not syncing the changes may be the problem.

The app runs prior to adding Firebase (it is the demo app in every newly created Flutter app)

Latest versions of Windows 10 and Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sync options are in your 'File' tab

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner, I do appreciate you answering my question.

Comment: we can search in Help for any option